# How do you match character OR end of string in a golang regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I am having trouble working out (in golang), within a regular expression, how to match a character, separator, or end of string.  The following does almost what I want:

```
url := "test20160101"
if i, _ := regexp.MatchString("[-a-zA-Z/]20[012]\\d[01]\\d[0123]\\d[-a-zA-Z/]", url); i == true {
    t := regexp.MustCompile("[-a-zA-Z/](20[012]\\d[01]\\d[0123]\\d)[-a-zA-Z/]").FindStringSubmatch(url)[1]
    fmt.Println("match: ", t)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eWZ_DiOVBl

But I want to also match the following:

```
url := "test-20160101-"
url := "/20160101/page.html"
```

I notice there is a \z in [the golang documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) however that doesn't work, at least when I put it inside `[-a-zA-Z/]` i.e. `[-a-zA-Z\\z/]`

Comment: Just a note about regex compile in case you get used to writing it like you did in the question. Regex compile is *expensive*. Do it once and store the result. Saw some code recently that did MustCompile in a loop. That was a very slow mistake.

Comment: Yes, you are not supposed to put `\z` in the character class. It would match a literal `z` in there.

Comment: @ZanLynx Good pointer. Its just test code for me, but we wouldn't want people to emulate it.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, that is what my tests seem to indicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was interested and played around with it just for fun. Maybe something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/GRVnHTwW0g

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    // Want to match "test-20160101", "/20160101/" and "test-20160101"

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`[-a-zA-Z/](20[012]\d[01]\d[0123]\d)([-a-zA-Z/]|\z)`)
    urls := []string{
        "test-20160101",
        "/20160101/page.html",
        "test20160101",
        "nomatch",
        "test19990101",
    }

    for _, url := range urls {
        t := re.FindStringSubmatch(url)
        if len(t) > 2 {
            fmt.Println("match", url, "=", t[1])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Life-saver. This solves it perfectly. I'll ammend your post as well to  clarify that there could be more at the end of the url

Answer (score 3):

Put a `?` at the end of the pattern. That means the preceding item is optional.

If you want to anchor the pattern to match at the end of the string, put a `$` (or `\z`) at the very end (after the `?`).

Also, you should use backquotes instead of double quotes around your RE. That way you don't have to escape the backslashes.

And as @Zan Lynx mentioned, only compile the RE once.

Comment: Helpful reply, however there could be more in the string, otherwise I would have done that. I will update the question to clarify this.